# Passing variables between windows forms in VS 2010

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, variables

I have two forms. Form 1 allows the user to pick an employee from a dropdown combo box. That employee is then passed onto Form 2 where the user enters additional information regarding that employee. That data will then be passed into a SQL table.

On form 1 I have:

```
Dim ChangeJobInfo As New Form2(Employee)
ChangeJobInfo.Show()
```

On Form 2 I have:

```
Public Sub New(ByVal Employee As String)
MsgBox(Employee)
End Sub
```

The variable passes just fine. The issue is that nothing shows up on the new form. When I setup Form2, I added a combobox, date picker, two text boxes, submit button, etc., but when the form loads it is completely blank. No errors, the MsgBox returns the right result, but none of my gui elements show up. If I change the code on form 1 to Form2.show() I see the form as laid out in the designer.

Any ideas on how to get those items to show up?

Comment: So you just didn't yet write the code to put the field values of Employee into the controls?  The required InitializeComponent() call is missing as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change your code in Form2.vb for the `New` sub to this:

```
Public Sub New(ByVal Employee As String)

    ' This call is required by the designer.

    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

    MsgBox(Employee)

End Sub
```

If you don't call `InitializeComponent()`, your complete GUI is not going to render.

Comment: Thank you, I had made that change prior to seeing your answer and came here to post the solution. What I find frustrating is that (IMHO) you should see that call every time a windows form loads so new programmers like myself know it needs to be there.

Comment: You're welcome. I do get what you're saying, however, if you were to go to Form2.vb's code and select "Form2" in the top left drop down and "New" in the top right drop down, it would have populated the `InitializeComponent()` and comments for you.

Answer (score 5):

You don't even have to use the InitializeComponent or New functions.

I have made an example to show how easily this can be done.

[image]

Clicking "Show Form" results in the below:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Form2.Show()
End Sub
```

which is simply used to display the second form.

By clicking "Pass Data" results in the following code:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Form2.Label1.Text = TextBox1.Text
End Sub
```

As shown above you can pass the data directly from control to control. The same idea can be used with variables too.

Comment: My issue wasn't with the code, it was the lack of the initialize call.

Comment: @gwhenning Maybe so, but people viewing the question based on the title  may find the answer helpful, since this answer is what I wanted to find, and it makes the most sense given the question's title.

Answer (score 1):

I am late but I think this answer can help.

For example, Form1 named "menu" opens and passes variable to Form2 named "ordine".
The variable to pass is "hotel"

In menu on button_click

```
Dim ordinef As New Ordine()

If ordinef Is Nothing Then
    'control that form is not opened yet if open close before
    ordinef = New Ordine()
Else
    ordinef.Close()
    ordinef = New Ordine()
End If

ordinef.hotel = hotel

ordinef.Show()
```

In Form2 (Ordine):

```
Private Sub Ordine_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

public hotel as string

msgbox hotel
```

That's it!!

Comment: Thank you for the late response, the issue wasn't passing the variables, it was that none of the UI controls were initializing. I had to add InitializeComponent() to get the UI controls to show up.

Comment: Yes I understand but with this code you can pass as much as variables as you want each time you need to open the form (sometimes you may need to pass 1 sometimes 20). It's quite easier.