# get ID from datagridview and show the data to another form in textboxes

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Im kind of new in vb.net. I have a datagridview that shows the Delivery Number, Date and supplier. Now, I want the Admin to view the details of every delivery to another form. I just want to know how will I get the id of the selected row and then will be able to display the equivalent data of that selected ID. Thanks.

Here's my code for the Deliveries Form.

```
Private Sub dgvDeliveryReport_CellContentDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgvDeliveryReport.CellContentDoubleClick
        If e.RowIndex < 0 Then Exit Sub

        Dim id As Int32 = dgvDeliveryReport.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value
        Dim viewDelivery As New frmDeliveryFormReport
        frmDeliveryFormReport.Show()
    End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of just passing the id to the other form you could pass the whole row to it. Then you can show all the data you want. Just add a parameter of type `DataGridViewRow` to the `frmDeliveryFormReport` constructor and pass `dgvDeliveryReport.CurrentRow` to it.

Comment: Do you have something to show me how does it work? Like forums, tutorials or codes to do it? Like I said Im new to vb.net. So I can't visualize how will I do it. Thanks.

Comment: I added an answer. Please take it look if it helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- In your `frmDeliveryFormReport` class add a new field to store current row:

  `private _currentDeliveryReportRow as DataGridViewRow`
- Look for the constructor:

  ```
  Public Sub New frmDeliveryFormReport()
    ...
  End Sub
  ```

  (If you cannot find it just proceed with the next step).
- Change/Add the constructor so it takes the `DataGridViewRow` parameter and store the given row:

  ```
  Public Sub New frmDeliveryFormReport(deliveryReportRow as DataGridViewRow)
     _currentDeliveryReportRow = deliveryReportRow 
  End Sub
  ```
- Adapt your existing `dgvDeliveryReport_CellContentDoubleClick` to call the new constructor:

  ```
  Private Sub dgvDeliveryReport_CellContentDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgvDeliveryReport.CellContentDoubleClick
      If e.RowIndex < 0 Then Exit Sub

      Dim viewDelivery As New frmDeliveryFormReport(dgvDeliveryReport.CurrentRow)
      frmDeliveryFormReport.Show()
  End Sub
  ```

You can then access all columns of the DeliveryReportRow in the frmDeliveryFormReport via

```
_currentDeliveryReportRow.Cells(<CellIndex>)
```

---

**Additional information about this topic:**

> [Passing variables between windows forms in VS 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17707795/passing-variables-between-windows-forms-in-vs-2010)
>
> [VB.Net Passing values to another form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19618668/vb-net-passing-values-to-another-form)
>
> http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/332553-passing-data-between-forms/

Answer (score 0):

Try.

```
Dim newFrmName as new yourForm

For each row as DataGridViewRow in SampleGrid
    if row.selected = true then
        Dim whatValueYouWant as string = row.cells("ID").value.toString()
        if newFrmName.NameOfTextBoxInForm.Text <> vbEmpty Then
            'NameOfTextBoxInForm is textbox that existing in yourform
            newFrmName.NameOfTextBoxInForm.text = ", " & whatValueYouWant
        Else
            newFrmName.NameOfTextBoxInForm.text = whatValueYouWant
        End If
    End IF
Next

newFrmName.Show()
```

Comment: Sir Jsun, what is SampleGrid above?